# put web page content to array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get some data about temperature and relative humidity of the city from a website (e.g. http://www.example.com/weather.htm).

The source code of this website

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><span><pre id='ming'>
18-7-2016           
            temperature     
Hong Kong     20.3               
London        16.8               
Washington    15.2                  

              relative humidity

Hong Kong            80%
London               75%
Washington           60%    
</pre></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I define an array about sort of city before and then I use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get data.

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$c=array("London","Washington","Hong Kong");
$temp=array();
$rh=array();
$date="";
$html = file_get_html('test.htm');
foreach($html->find('pre#ming') as $e)
    $links[] = $e->innertext . '<br>';

print_r($links);
?>
```

The $link array show out

```
Array ( [0] => 18-7-2016 temperature Hong Kong 20.3 London 16.8 Washington 15.2 relative humidity Hong Kong 80% London 75% Washington 60% 
)
```

How can I get the date,temperature and relative humidity data from $link and put it into $date,$temp and $rh ($temp and $rh sort by $c)?

For example, array should be:

```
//$temp 
Array
(
    [0] => 16.8
    [1] => 15.2
    [2] => 20.3
)

//$rh
Array
(
    [0] => 16.8
    [1] => 15.2
    [2] => 20.3
)
```

Comment: Depending on if you are sure there will only be X cities each time (where X is known), you can use either explode() or preg_match / preg_match_all to get every part.

Comment: @Julqas Cities X is known but how to get the data form array $link?

Comment: With explode for example, you can do `$data = explode(' ',$link[0]);`to have every expression into a new array. By exploring this array you extract your data. It's not very clean, I would recommend a REGEXP here, using preg_match_all for example :) !

Comment: @Julqas How to use preg_match_all to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the content structure of the site never changes

```
<?php

  $mainArray = Array ( 0 => "18-7-2016 temperature Hong Kong 20.3 London 16.8 Washington 15.2 relative humidity Hong Kong 80% London 75% Washington 60%");
  $dateArray = [];

  foreach($mainArray as $data):

  list($date,$arr) = explode(" ",$data,2);
  $dateArray[] = $date;

  // taking index 
  $tempIndex = strpos($arr,"temperature");
  $rhIndex = strpos($arr,"relative humidity");

  // taking substring with only city and its value
  $tempString = substr($arr,strlen("temperature ") + $tempIndex,($rhIndex - (strlen("temperature ") + $tempIndex)));
  $rhString = substr($arr,strlen("relative humidity ") + $rhIndex);

  $cityArray = ["Hong Kong","London","Washington"];
  $tempArray = [];
  $rhArray = [];

  foreach($cityArray as $city):

      // extracting temperature values
      if(strpos($tempString,$city) !== FALSE):
          $tempArray[$city] = substr($tempString,strpos($tempString,$city) + strlen($city) + 1);
          $splitArray = explode(" ",$tempArray[$city]);
          $tempArray[$city] = $splitArray[0];

      endif;

       // extracting humidity values
      if(strpos($rhString,$city) !== FALSE):
          $rhArray[$city] = substr($tempString,strpos($tempString,$city) + strlen($city) + 1);
          $splitArray = explode(" ",$rhArray[$city]);
          $rhArray[$city] = $splitArray[0];
      endif;
  endforeach;

  print_r($tempArray);echo "<br>";
  print_r($rhArray);

  endforeach;
  print_r($dateArray);
?>
```

This would give you the following result

```
//temperature
Array ( [Hong Kong] => 20.3 [London] => 16.8 [Washington] => 15.2 ) 

//rh
Array ( [Hong Kong] => 20.3 [London] => 16.8 [Washington] => 15.2 )

//date
Array ( [0] => 18-7-2016 )
```

Comment: How can i get the date 18-7-2016? Add new Index?

Comment: How do you want the date values ?? As a different array ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Now you will get all date values as array.

Comment: Now date is not connected with the other data , But a simple tweak will let you have the date as index for the final array and connect them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REGEXP for example to extract all the data you want.
Here is an ugly and static example but it's for you to get the point :

```
preg_match('#[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z ]+([\d.]+)[a-zA-Z ]+([\d.]+)[a-zA-Z ]+([\d.]+)[a-zA-Z ]+([\d.]+)[a-zA-Z% ]+([\d.]+)[a-zA-Z% ]+([\d.]+)#',$link[0],$matches);
```

would return

```
MATCH 1
1.  [32-36] `20.3`
2.  [44-48] `16.8`
3.  [60-64] `15.2`
4.  [93-95] `80`
5.  [104-106]   `75`
6.  [119-121]   `60`
```

You also can have another approach, doing you regexp like this `([0-9.]+)` and not taking the first 3 that are for the date, etc..

Comment: This solution is fine but i want the result like //$temp 
Array
(
    [0] => 16.8
    [1] => 15.2
    [2] => 20.3
)

//$rh
Array
(
    [0] => 16.8
    [1] => 15.2
    [2] => 20.3
)

Comment: I won't do the work for you, it's not the goal :) You now have a clue to go a little farther, you have a new approach to extract the data from your variable $links, you have to decide which way you want to use, and manage the extracted data to make your two arrays

Answer (score 0):

If they ever change the format of the content on that site you have a problem, but with this array I would do something like this:

```
$arr = Array ( 0 =>' 18-7-2016 temperature Hong Kong 20.3 London 16.8 Washington 15.2 relative humidity Hong Kong 80% London 75% Washington 60% 
    ');
$c=array("London","Washington","Hong Kong");

//SPLIT STRING on TEMPRATURE
$tmp = explode('temperature' , $arr[0]);
//GET PART BEFORE temperature
//REMOVE SPACES FROM FRONT and END
$date = trim($tmp[0]);

//GET OTHER PARTS
$tmp = explode('relative humidity' , $tmp[1]);
$temperature = $tmp[0];         
$humidity = $tmp[1];

function get_city($city,$a){
    $regex='/(\b'.$city.'\b\s+)(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))/';
    preg_match($regex,$a,$matches);
    if(isset($matches[0])){
        $ret = str_replace($city,'',$matches[0]);
        $ret = str_replace(' ','',$ret);
        return $ret;
        }
    else{
        return false;
        }
    }

foreach($c as $nr=>$city){
    $temp[$nr] = get_city($city,$temperature);
    }
foreach($c as $nr=>$city){
    echo $humidity.'<br>';
    $hum[$nr] = get_city($city,' '.$humidity);
    }

echo $date.'<br>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($temp,true).'</pre><br>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($hum,true).'</pre><br>';
```

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that part :-)

Comment: I changed the answer to meet your requirement of sorting.